# Http request Unresponsive : Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat

We have deployed our application on a Apache Tomcat server.

Few users are facing an issue when invoking one of the API endpoint where they are not getting any response back from the server and there request is going unresponsive.

This issue is intermittent.

I am assuming that all the threads in Tomcat thread pool  during that time were busy and hence the request wasn't handled.

I read about Tomcat maxConnection and accept-count parameter.

I need clarification on is that Apache Tomcat server would reject http request when all the threads handling the imcoming http request are busy and the queue that holds unprocessed http request are full at Same time ?

Answer (score 0):

If the request queue has `acceptCount` requests waiting, then subsequent requests will be refused. [From the apache tomcat documentation:](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html)

> **acceptCount:** The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all
>   possible request processing threads are in use. Any requests received
>   when the queue is full will be refused. The default value is 100.

From your question you state that uses are not getting a response back from the server, which indicates the request is not being immediately refused, but hanging. If your application connects to a database then you might want to check the threadpool size and peformance of your datasource, and if you connect to 3rd party services over the network, then the bottleneck might lie there, or indeed be IO bound. If the tomcat was refusing connections you would an immediate response.

Comment: Http Requests never made never reached our API endpoint at all.